# conflict between Beamer and covington? (Using Beamer 3.50)

Tags: beamer, covington

Is there a conflict between Beamer (3.50 of 2018/02/20) and covington (1.4 of 2017/05/23)? This (hopefully) simple document:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{covington}

\makeatletter

\XeTeXdashbreakstate 0

\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}
\def\glosstr{}
\@ifundefined{linggloss}{%
\newenvironment{linggloss}[2][]{
        \def\glosstr{\glt #1}%
        \gll #2}
{\glosstr\glend}}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}
\title{Are Czech conditionals with an infinitival condition all Counterfactual?}
\makebeamertitle
\begin{frame}{And how does it look inCzech?}
    \begin{covexamples}
        \item real conditions – realistic, achievable, achieved?
        \item \begin{linggloss}[If Vašek comes on time we'll make it without any problems.]
            Když přijde        Vašek        včas,   tak  to          stihneme      v  pohodě.
            If   come-3sg.pres Vašek-nom.sg on time then that-acc.sg make-1pl.pres in ease.
        \end{linggloss}
    \end{covexamples}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Leads to error in compilation:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.44
```

This gloss looks to me exactly like what's on page 7 of
http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington/covington.pdf What's wrong with me?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without special fonts? This might increase the number of people who can potentially help you.

Comment: @samcarter Sure it has nothing to do with fonts. Just delete all ``\set*font`` lines. And it is all from ``covington`` package. https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington/covington.pdf

Comment: You can get the code to compile by using `\begin{frame}[fragile]` -- I don't understand what your nested `linggloss` environment should do, so idea if a fragile frames solved the problem.

Comment: To find the source of the problem it would be helpful if you could remove all unnecessary code and simply your example to use only the macros from the package instead of your custom wrappers and also include what the expected output is.

Comment: Just to reiterate what @samcarter is saying: please cook your example down to the relevant ingredients. (And no, we are not asking you to give us instructions which lines we are supposed to delete, please edit your code.) Then I am pretty confident that an answer will emerge.

Comment: Off-topic: the `\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%` is really unnecessary. Simply use `\maketitle`. If it used outside a frame environment, beamer will automatically create a frame around it.

Comment: @samcarter The ``[fragile]]`` is the solution, thank you. If you make it into answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example can be compiled by using a `fragile` frame.

Unrelated to the problem: your custom `\makebeamertitle` macro is unnecessary, beamer defines `\maketitle` to automatically create a frame around the titlepage if `\maketitle` is used outside a frame environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{covington}

\makeatletter
\def\glosstr{}
\@ifundefined{linggloss}{%
\newenvironment{linggloss}[2][]{
        \def\glosstr{\glt #1}%
        \gll #2}
{\glosstr\glend}}{}
\makeatother

\title{Are Czech conditionals with an infinitival condition all Counterfactual?}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{And how does it look inCzech?}
    \begin{covexamples}
        \item real conditions – realistic, achievable, achieved?
        \item \begin{linggloss}[If Vašek comes on time we'll make it without any problems.]
            Když přijde        Vašek        včas,   tak  to          stihneme      v  pohodě.
            If   come-3sg.pres Vašek-nom.sg on time then that-acc.sg make-1pl.pres in ease.
        \end{linggloss}
    \end{covexamples}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mcepl You're welcome!